# How to get the time in seconds after click on submit button using React Count Down Timer

Tags: reactjs, countdowntimer

```
const renderer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds }) => { 
        return <span>{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}</span>;
    }
    
<span ><CountDown date={Date.now() + 18000}
renderer={renderer}/></span>
                                        
<button onClick={onButtonClick} >Submit</button>
```

i have used here react-countdown npm package

Once we load the page the timer will be on and I need to get the remaining time when click on submit button

Comment: add sample https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works and I don't have time to make it prettier -- here ya go

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

// Random component
const Completionist = () => <span>You are good to go!</span>;

const renderer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds }) => {  return <span>{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}</span>; }

const cd = <Countdown date = {Date.now() + 18000} rend={renderer}/>

const endDate = Date.now() + 18000


function onButtonClick() {
  const currentDate = Date.now();
  
  const diff = (currentDate - endDate) / -1000;
  console.log(diff)
  
}






ReactDOM.render(
  
  <><span>{cd}</span><button onClick={onButtonClick} >Submit</button></>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Functional over pretty any day of the week and twice on Sundays

Comment: @ShankarPechimuthu if it worked for you, upvote his answer and select it as the correct answer. Comments are nice, but this is how to truly show your appreciation for the help.

Comment: thanks for the assist @hfontanez -- my first accepted answer!

Comment: @ShankarPechimuthu you haven't accepted as the answer. You have to click the check mark. Which will appreciated, of course!

Comment: @LoganAyliffe I upvoted your answer, but you will have to wait for Shankar to do the right thing by upvoting AND selecting your answer.